# Vertical paragraph drift when using Paracol

Tags: vertical-alignment, paracol

I'm attempting my first document in two languages and I seem to be getting a vertical drift in my paragraph alignment. You can see things begin to shift with paragraph three. This is a short section, but other sections are much longer and the drift can be quite severe. I really need the paragraphs to adjust their vertical alignment so they stay in sync with one another.
[image: Paragraph Drift]

I've tried using \switchcolumn and leftcolumn / rightcolumn notation. Here's MWE of what I'm using currently for this section.

```
\documentclass[14pt,openany ]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,ignoreall,right=2cm, left=2cm,bottom=1.5cm,top=1.5cm]{geometry}
   
\usepackage[german, english]{babel}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em}
\setlength{\parskip}{14pt}

\begin{document}
\sloppy

\begin{paracol}{2}
\section*{§ 1 Grundregeln} 

(1) Die Teilnahme am Straßenverkehr erfordert ständige Vorsicht und gegenseitige Rücksicht.

(2) Wer am Verkehr teilnimmt hat sich so zu verhalten, dass kein Anderer geschädigt, gefährdet oder mehr, als nach den Umständen unvermeidbar, behindert oder belästigt wird.

Zu § 1 Grundregeln

1 I. Die Straßenverkehrs-Ordnung (StVO) regelt und lenkt den öffentlichen Verkehr.

2 II. Öffentlicher Verkehr findet auch auf nicht gewidmeten Straßen statt, wenn diese mit Zustimmung oder unter Duldung des Verfügungsberechtigten tatsächlich allgemein benutzt werden. Dagegen ist der Verkehr auf öffentlichen Straßen nicht öffentlich, solange diese, zum Beispiel wegen Bauarbeiten, durch Absperrschranken oder ähnlich wirksame Mittel für alle Verkehrsarten gesperrt sind.

3 III. Landesrecht über den Straßenverkehr ist unzulässig (vgl. Artikel 72 Abs. 1 in Verbindung mit Artikel 74 Nr. 22 des Grundgesetzes). Für örtliche Verkehrsregeln bleibt nur im Rahmen der StVO Raum.

\switchcolumn

\section*{§ 1 Basic rules} 

(1) Participation in road traffic requires constant caution and mutual consideration.

(2) Anyone participating in traffic must behave in such a way that no other person is harmed, endangered or obstructed or inconvenienced more than is unavoidable under the circumstances.

Re § 1 Basic rules

1 I. The Road Traffic Regulations (StVO) regulate and direct public traffic.

2 II. Public traffic also takes place on roads that have not been dedicated if they are actually in general use with the consent or acquiescence of the person entitled to dispose of them. On the other hand, traffic on public roads is not public as long as they are closed to all types of traffic, for example because of construction work, by barriers or similarly effective means.

3 III. state law on road traffic is inadmissible (cf. Article 72 (1) in conjunction with Article 74 No. 22 of the Basic Law). There is room for local traffic regulations only within the framework of the StVO.
\end{paracol}
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated but don't load both `enumerate` and `enumitem`, just the latter.

Comment: you need to use `\switchcolumn` to add the synchronisation points, so do first left para \swittchcolum 1st right para \switchcolum 2nd left para ....

Comment: oh it doesn't work, hmm

Comment: @campa, thank you for that. I'm always looking to streamline my package lists and code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I tried what you recommended and I ended up with the same results. I was hoping I wouldn't have to manually designate every paragraph as well as that can get quite tedious with large documents. I'll keep trying things and checking to see if you had any luck.

Comment: you definitely need to mark the synchronisation points (as you may for example only want to synchronise on section headings and not force alignment of every paragraph in some documents. But when I tried it, it didn't work I couldn't get any synchronisation with switchcolumn or begin{leftcolumn}  ... seems like a bug but I do not know the package well

Comment: I think I solved it. I tried using something I read earlier this morning on another question where you add a star after `\switchcolumn*`. I just marked every paragraph on the right and it straightened things out.

Comment: please self answer if you get it working, the documentation isn't at all clear here so I think a working example will help future readers:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get my text to align by marking all of the text in the right-hand column with a star (i.e., `\switchcolumn*`.

```
\documentclass[14pt,openany ]{book}

\usepackage[a4paper,ignoreall,right=2cm, left=2cm,bottom=1.5cm,top=1.5cm]{geometry}


\usepackage[german, english]{babel}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% Bibliography
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5em}
\setlength{\parskip}{14pt}

\begin{document}
\sloppy
\begin{paracol}{2}
\section*{§ 1 Grundregeln} 
\switchcolumn
\section*{§ 1 Basic rules} 
\switchcolumn*

(1) Die Teilnahme am Straßenverkehr erfordert ständige Vorsicht und gegenseitige Rücksicht.
\switchcolumn

(1) Participation in road traffic requires constant caution and mutual consideration.
\switchcolumn*

(2) Wer am Verkehr teilnimmt hat sich so zu verhalten, dass kein Anderer geschädigt, gefährdet oder mehr, als nach den Umständen unvermeidbar, behindert oder belästigt wird.
\switchcolumn

(2) Anyone participating in traffic must behave in such a way that no other person is harmed, endangered or obstructed, or inconvenienced more than is unavoidable under the circumstances.
\switchcolumn*

Zu § 1 Grundregeln
\switchcolumn

Re § 1 Basic rules
\switchcolumn*

1 I. Die Straßenverkehrs-Ordnung (StVO) regelt und lenkt den öffentlichen Verkehr.
\switchcolumn

1 I. The Road Traffic Regulations (StVO) regulate and direct public traffic.
\switchcolumn*

2 II. Öffentlicher Verkehr findet auch auf nicht gewidmeten Straßen statt, wenn diese mit Zustimmung oder unter Duldung des Verfügungsberechtigten tatsächlich allgemein benutzt werden. Dagegen ist der Verkehr auf öffentlichen Straßen nicht öffentlich, solange diese, zum Beispiel wegen Bauarbeiten, durch Absperrschranken oder ähnlich wirksame Mittel für alle Verkehrsarten gesperrt sind.
\switchcolumn

2 II. Public traffic also takes place on roads that have not been dedicated if they are actually in general use with the consent or acquiescence of the person entitled to dispose of them. On the other hand, traffic on public roads is not public as long as they are closed to all types of traffic, for example, because of construction work, by barriers, or similarly effective means.
\switchcolumn*

3 III. Landesrecht über den Straßenverkehr ist unzulässig (vgl. Artikel 72 Abs. 1 in Verbindung mit Artikel 74 Nr. 22 des Grundgesetzes). Für örtliche Verkehrsregeln bleibt nur im Rahmen der StVO Raum.
\switchcolumn

3 III. state law on road traffic is inadmissible (cf. Article 72 (1) in conjunction with Article 74 No. 22 of the Basic Law). There is room for local traffic regulations only within the framework of the StVO.
\switchcolumn*
\end{paracol}

\end{document}
```

[image: No More Drift]

Now the drift that I saw in paragraph three is gone.

Comment: I tried all no star and all star neither of which worked, good call to alternate the star and no star forms:-)

Comment: Yeah, I think the way it works is the star aligns to the previous switch point. When I tried the stars in the other order, it spread things out funny. Thanks for your help!